# How to change terminal printing color?

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

I'm new to this whole thing, and I'd like some help with my VSC.
If you see [the image I added here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cI8V7.png), you can see my terminal has this ugly white color when i run any code. I've tried with changing background and foreground color, and that's not helped.
The empty terminal has the regular color, it's whenever i run a code that this white color appears.
Any advice is helpful, thank you.

EDIT: It seems that the value "terminal.ansiWhite" is the one i need to modify, now what I want to do is see if there's a way to make it just not appear when running code. Will update

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why it's behaving like that, but I'm curious what happens if you put `print("\33[0m")` before printing some text?

It's an [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for resetting any previously printed codes.

Also, adding the visual-studio-code tag would probably yield better answers.

Comment: It stays the same, and the code prints "←[0m". I'll add the tag, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This dev guide may help with that, here's the [link](https://dev.to/sfarias051/how-to-change-the-terminal-style-in-vscode-in-an-easy-way-5139).

Comment: Hey there, this helped a little, now the color that was white is light brown so it can be modified. I'll see if I can make it just not be there. Thanks